# How to pass log4j configuration file to spark-submit on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I'm trying to launch a spark job in windows using `spark-submit`. The Spark application works fine without specifying logging options.

With the following `--driver-java-options`:

```
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///d:/launch/log4j-spark.properties"
```

I get the error message:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I tried many combinations but no luck, please advise.

```
spark-submit --master local[*]  --files D:\launch\log4j-spark.properties --jars D:\launch\spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.10-2.1.0.jar \
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///d:/launch/log4j-spark.properties"  \
--class com.acheron.bi.pipeline.DataPipelineProcessor D:\launch\bi-master-pipeline-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file://./launch/log4j-spark.properties"  \
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-spark.properties"  \
```

below is the folder containing the code

```
D:\launch>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 52DE-C096

 Directory of D:\launch

10/20/2017  10:06 AM    <DIR>          .
10/20/2017  10:06 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/20/2017  09:46 AM       111,631,778 bi-master-pipeline-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
10/20/2017  09:35 AM             1,394 event-win.yml
10/20/2017  09:58 AM               483 log4j-spark.properties
10/19/2017  01:19 PM               488 prod.env.properties
09/07/2017  09:35 AM           232,649 spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.10-2.1.0.jar
               5 File(s)    111,866,792 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  152,071,843,840 bytes free
```

Comment: Can you show the path using cmd? Use `dir`. This is to make sure the file is there (I'm on macOS so I'm gonna guess the format). Can you try `file:/D:/launch/log4j-spark.properties`?

Comment: I update the question with directory details, and file:/D:/launch/log4j-spark.properties did not help

Comment: Can you show the entire error message with `spark-submit`?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run windows `cmd` and successfully start spark application with following command and with my custom `my-log4j.properties`.

If you don't have white spaces in your path to `log4j.properties` you can omit quotes:

```
spark-submit.cmd --master local[*]  --driver-java-options -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///c:/tools/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/my-log4j.properties --class testjob.Main sparkjob.jar
```